# Both sides are sticking after symmetrize

Tags: sculpting, sculpt-mode

I created a sphere and then split it in two to have just one part, so I started sculpting a character's buttocks and used 15mm on a Remesh... Now I want to put even more resolution with Remesh and I put 10mm but this happens in the Image. Is it because the two parties are so close that this is happening? Is there any way to resolve it? I want it to look like a normal human body with that space between the buttocks.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The vertices of the two sides ended up "meeting" in the center of the object and forming one. I deleted the part that I had used Symmetrize in Edit Mode and put the Mirror Modifier

Comment: You could just enable merge in the mirror modifier or do "Merge by Distance" in Edit Mode.

Answer (score 0):

The space in the center is probably 20mm, it result fom the remesh + the mirror (10mm x 2) so it explain wha you have a lower resolution in this area.
If set lower than the current face size the remesh will "erase" details.

Comment: I found the problem but thanks for the information